# Trying to use WF2010 to update lookup value

Tags: workflow

I have created 2 lists A & B.  A contains a date/time field. This field is included as a

lookup column within list B.

I have created a 2010 workflow which kicks when an item in list A is created. A calender date

is selected in List A and a create list item is invoked on list B which should copy the date

from A and show it as the selected field within list B.

The workflow will not copy the value from A to B.  Thank you for any advice on this

Comment: Was the workflow created in SPD? or VS?

Comment: It was created in SPD

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of your workflow.